# Adding two boolean dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I currently have two Boolean dataframes which look like the following:

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

I need to multiply df1 by +1 and df2 by -1 and add the two data frames together, such as to get df3 which should look like the below and has a +1 from any TRUE value in df1 and a -1 from any TRUE value in df2.

df3

[image]

how do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried and which problems did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert to int using `df.astype` and add them:

```
df1.astype(int) + df2.astype(int).mul(-1)
```

---

Demo:

```
In [709]: df1
Out[709]: 
       A      B      C      D      E
0   True  False  False  False  False
1   True  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False   True
3   True   True  False   True   True
4   True  False  False  False   True
5   True  False  False   True  False
6  False  False   True  False   True
7   True   True  False  False   True
8   True  False  False  False   True
9  False   True  False   True   True

In [710]: df2
Out[710]: 
       A      B      C      D      E
0   True  False   True  False  False
1  False   True  False   True  False
2  False  False  False   True   True
3   True  False  False   True  False
4   True   True  False   True  False
5  False   True  False   True   True
6   True  False   True  False  False
7   True  False   True   True   True
8  False   True   True   True  False
9  False  False  False  False  False

In [711]: df1.astype(int) + df2.astype(int).mul(-1)
Out[711]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0 -1  0  0
1  1 -1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0 -1  0
3  0  1  0  0  1
4  0 -1  0 -1  1
5  1 -1  0  0 -1
6 -1  0  0  0  1
7  0  1 -1 -1  0
8  1 -1 -1 -1  1
9  0  1  0  1  1
```